# How to promisify this Mongoose code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I am trying to use Mongoose's built in promise support to write some clean Javascript code for a user sending a friend request to another. However, when I try to ensure proper error handling and sequentiality, I still end up with a (slightly smaller than normal) pyramid of doom.

Here, I first ensure that the friend request is valid, then save the target's Id to the requester's sent requests then, if that save was successful, save the requester's Id to the target's friend requests.

Do I need to use a third party library like q in order to do this as cleanly as possible? How can I structure this such that I can use the traditional single error handler at the end?

```
function _addFriend (requesterId, targetId) {
// (integer, integer)
User.findById(requesterId)
.exec((requester) => {
    if (!(targetId in requester.friends
    || targetId in requester.sentfriendRequests
    || targetId in requester.friendRequests)) {
        requester.sentfriendRequests = requester.sentfriendRequests.concat([targetId])
        requester.save()
        .then((err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        User.findById(targetId)
        .exec((err, target) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            target.friendRequests = target.friendRequests.concat([requesterId])
            target.save().then(err => {if (err) throw err})
            })
        })
    }
})
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the first `exec` callback doesn't need an `err` parameter?

Comment: `.then(err => {if (err) throw err})` doesn't look like you should need it with promises

Answer (score 1):

In English, the way to do this is to use the promises returned by `exec()` have `then` blocks return promises, un-indent, then add `then` to those.  Much easier to say in code...

**EDIT** thanks (again) to @Bergi for making me read and understand the app logic.  @Bergi is right that there must be a little nesting to get the job done, but the real point isn't about reducing nesting, but about improving clarity.

Better clarity can come from factoring into logical parts, including some that return in promises.

These few functions conceal the promise nesting that's required by the logic.  This doesn't specify (because the OP doesn't indicate how the app should handle) what addFriend should return when it refuses to do so due to an existing request...

```
function _addFriend (requesterId, targetId) {
    // note - pass no params to exec(), use it's returned promise
    return User.findById(requesterId).exec().then((requester) => {
        return canAddFriend(requester, targetId) ? addFriend(requester, targetId) : null;
    });
}

function canAddFriend(requester, targetId) {
    return requester && targetId &&
        !(targetId in requester.friends
          || targetId in requester.sentfriendRequests
          || targetId in requester.friendRequests);
}

function addFriend(requester, targetId) {
    requester.sentfriendRequests = requester.sentfriendRequests.concat([targetId]);
    return requester.save().then(() => {
        return User.findById(targetId).exec();
    }).then((target) => {
        target.friendRequests = target.friendRequests.concat([requesterId]);
        return target.save();
    });
}
```

Comment: You *did* flubb the logic, all what follows `doStuff` should be inside that `if` body

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I think I just missed the close brace.  Lemme know if that's not what you're saying.

Comment: No, I didn't mean braces, I meant the whole action that begins with `requester.save()` that needs to go inside the `if` condition

Comment: @Bergi - probably either a no-op if the object isn't dirtied, or harmless if not a no-op.  Added an alternative anyway.

Comment: But you're still adding the requester to the friend requests of the target, even when he already is in there!

Answer (score 1):

You *will* need some nesting to do conditionals in promise code, but not as much  as with callback-based code.

You seem to have messed up a bit of the `if (err) throw err;` stuff, you should never need that with promises. Just always use `.then(result => {…})`, and don't pass callbacks to `exec` any more.

If you always properly `return` promises from your asynchronous functions (including `then` callbacks for chaining), you can add the single error handler in the end.

```
function _addFriend (requesterId, targetId) {
// (integer, integer)
    return User.findById(requesterId).exec().then(requester => {
        if (targetId in requester.friends
          || targetId in requester.sentfriendRequests
          || targetId in requester.friendRequests) {
            return;
        }
        requester.sentfriendRequests = requester.sentfriendRequests.concat([targetId])
        return requester.save().then(() => {
            return User.findById(targetId).exec()
        }).then(target => {
            target.friendRequests = target.friendRequests.concat([requesterId])
            return target.save()
        });
    });
}

_addFriend(…).catch(err => {
    …
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you realise that `.exec()` returns a promise, you can :

- achieve the desired flattening and make the code more readable.
- avoid the need to handle errors amongst the "success" code.
- handle errors in a terminal .then() or .catch().

As a bonus you can also (more readily) throw meaningful errors for each of those `x in y` conditions.

Straightforwardly, you could write :

```
function _addFriend(requesterId, targetId) {
    return User.findById(requesterId).exec().then(requester => {
        if (targetId in requester.friends) {
            throw new Error('target is already a friend');
        }
        if (targetId in requester.sentfriendRequests) { 
            throw new Error('friend request already sent to target');
        }
        if (targetId in requester.friendRequests) {
            throw new Error('target already sent a friend request to requester');
        }
        requester.sentfriendRequests = requester.sentfriendRequests.concat([targetId]); // or just .push()?
        return requester.save();
    }).then(() => {
        return User.findById(targetId).exec().then(target => {
            target.friendRequests = target.friendRequests.concat([requesterId]); // or just .push()?
            return target.save();
        });
    });
}
```

*Note the need for returns to control flow.*

But you could do even better. As writtten above, the requested stuff could succeed then the target stuff fail, resulting in a db disparity. So what you really want is a db transaction to guarantee that both happen or neither. Mongoose undoubtedly provides for transactions however you can do something client-side to give you something transaction-like with partial benefit.

```
function _addFriend(requesterId, targetId) {
    return Promise.all([User.findById(requesterId).exec(), User.findById(targetId).exec()]).then(([requester, target]) => { // note destructuring
        if (targetId in requester.friends) {
            throw new Error('target is already a friend');
        }
        if (targetId in requester.sentfriendRequests) { 
            throw new Error('friend request already sent to target');
        }
        if (targetId in requester.friendRequests) {
            throw new Error('target already sent a friend request to requester');
        }
        requester.sentfriendRequests = requester.sentfriendRequests.concat([targetId]);
        target.friendRequests = target.friendRequests.concat([requesterId]);
        return requester.save().then(() => {
            return target.save();
        });
    });
}
```

Here, you could still get the (unlikely) situation that the first save is successful and the second save fails, but at least you have the assurance that absolutely nothing happens unless both the requester and target exist.

In both cases, call as follows :

```
_addFriend(requesterId, targetId).then(function() {
    // do whatever on success
}, function(error) {
    // do whatever on error
});
```

Even if you don't use the error messages in the live environment, they could be very useful when testing/debugging. Please check them - I may have gotten them wrong.